# Spark read files from AWS S3 process

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

In Spark, if the data files are in AWS S3 (object store), how are the blocks of the files read by the executor, how do the executor co-ordinate i.e. executor 1 reads block1 (1-128 MB) and executor 2 reads block2 (128 to 256MB). How is the entire process managed and who manages it?

Secondly how are the objects broken down to blocks?

Answer (score 0):

aws s3 api allows to read only a range of the file. Executor is splitting the file in defined size and assigns a partition to every data node. Every data node will read his partition only.